# python cherrypy installation

Tags: python, cherrypy

I'm trying to get python with cherrypy running on Ubuntu.

i installed python via

```
sudo apt-get update
sudp apt-get install python3.6
```

and cherrypy via

```
git clone https://github.com/cherrypy/cherrypy
cd cherrypy
python setup.py install
```

But when i try to test it via

```
python -m cherrypy.tutorial.tut01_helloworld
```

i get the error message "no module found named parse".
Running it via

```
python3.6 -m cherrypy.tutorial.tut01_helloworld
```

results in an error "no module found named cherrypy".

Answer (score 0):

`python` invokes Python 2.7. `parse` is not available in this version. CherryPy can not be imported, because the path to CherryPy is not in your `sys.path`. It is better to install CherryPy over pip. CherryPy > 17.4.0 only works with Python 3!